# Channel Entry Form not found

Tags: ee2, safecracker, forms, entry

I've picked up some work on a site (EEv2.8.1) which requires a channel entry form so users can publish their own channel entries. It's been a long, long time since I have worked with this area of a site so my first stop was to look at the Safecracker module. I learned that the module is now integrated into EE as of V2.

So my next step was to use the built in `{exp:channel:entry_form}`. I popped the tags into my template and then on reload I reveieved an error saying that the tags could not be processed and to '*Please check that the ‘channel’ module is installed and that ‘entry_form’ is an available method of the module*'. The channel module was indeed installed.

On checking the channel module files, it was missing the 'mod.channel_standalone.php file. I managed to track this file down from another EE install. But I'm still getting the error that the `{exp:channel:entry_form}` is not being recognised.

Am I missing something? Can anyone help me out with this? Like I said, it's been a while since I dealt with something like this so I may have overlooked something. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Typical that as soon as I post a question I find, what I think is, the solution. It seems the tags are not `{exp:channel:entry_form}` but `{exp:channel:form}` instead.